# Save specific Json from specifiq request link

Tags: json, request, puppeteer

I want to scrape specific JSON from specific request link "http://website.com/request/api" on page.

I have to scroll to the bottom of the page to get all the articles (already coded). At each scroll, I would like to get the JSON corresponding to the articles just displayed.

So there are 2 problems:

1. The fact that the same URL query "http://website.com/request/api" is also used to returns other JSON which is not useful for me (other elements of the page).
2. The fact of having several JSONs to collect and assemble

For problem 1, I thought of adding a condition to my code to get only the JSON beginning with a precise text "Data : object"?

For the problem 2, I should be able to write in a file or the buffer the different JSON selected by assembling them.

Do you know how I could do it?

```
page.on('response', async(response) => {   const request => response.request();
  if (request.url().includes('/api/graphql/')){
    const text = await response.text();
    fs.writeFile('./tmp/response.json', JSON.stringify((text)));
    console.log(text);   
  } 
})
```

Comment: This is rather difficult to assist with without seeing the full code and actual website/markup/responses you're dealing with, or (ideally) [mcve] of these items.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolve the problem.

```js
listener = page.on('response', async response => {
  const isXhr = ['xhr','fetch','json'].includes(response.request().resourceType())
  try {
  if (isXhr){
    if (response.url().includes('/api/graphql/')) {
    const resp = await response.buffer();
    if (resp.includes('Data : object')) {
  fs.writeFileSync('./tmp/response.json', resp, { flag: 'a+' })
 
    }
    }
  }}
  catch(e){}
})
```